# Ajax não funciona com botão específico

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, button

Tenho um código que ao clicar no botão ele pede um motivo do clique. Depois de escrever o motivo ele troca o botão e deveria trocar as informações listadas em baixo. Esse código está em **Ajax** só que não está funcionando corretamente.
Ao clicar nesse botão, ele pede essa justificativa e troca o botão, mas não troca as informações. **OBS:** O mesmo código funciona com o outro botão que desabilita a imagem que eu tenho, mas com esse botão não funciona.

A parte que não está funcionando é essa:

```
success: function(r) {
    if(r) {
        $(t).parent().parent().next().find('.msg_SemEmi').show();                        
        $(t).parent().parent().next().find('.graf_laudo').show();                        
        $(t).parent().parent().next().find('.graf_lau').css('display','none');
        $(t).parent().parent().next().find('.img_lau_d').show();
        $(t).parent().parent().next().find('.img_lau_a').css('display','none');
        $(t).removeClass('semEmi btn-default');
        $(t).addClass('comEmi btn-warning');
        $(t).empty();
        $(t).append('<span class="btn-label"><i class="fa fa-check-square-o"></i></span><?= $this->lang->line("con_inflaud_afe_comEmi"); ?>');
    } else {
        notifica('<?= $this->lang->line("con_inflaud_msg_erro_title"); ?>', '<?= $this->lang->line("con_inflaud_msg_erro_d"); ?>', 4000);
    }
}
```

Aqui está o HTML que chama esse Ajax:

```
<div class="btn_semEmi">
    <input type="hidden" id="input_semEmi<?= $l->img_id ?>" name="id_foto" value="<?= $l->img_id ?>">
    <a href="javascript:void(0);" id="semEmi<?= $l->img_id ?>"  id-foto="<?= $l->img_id ?>" class="btn btn-labeled btn-default pull-right semEmi"> <span class="btn-label"><i class="fa fa-ban"></i></span><?= $this->lang->line("con_inflaud_afe_semEmi"); ?></a>
</div>
```

Meu código está em MVC

Comment: Alguma mensagem de erro no console do navegador?

Comment: Se você entender inglês, por favor, leia [essa resposta](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3133540/1267304).

Comment: Coloque todo o código referente ao AJAX como por exemplo essa variável `t`, o que ela representa? O que exatamente o código deveria fazer que não está fazendo? Você conseguiu identificar em qual parte do código está o problema? O que quer dizer "_mas não troca as informações_", está falando desses códigos `.parent().parent()...`? Se for coloque o HTML que representa essa estrutura.

Comment: @KaduAmaral agradeço sua preocupação, mas consegui arrumar apenas chamando pelo id o que precissava. Obrigada!

Comment: De nada @Ketlin, você poderia por favor postar a sua solução como resposta aqui? É só clicar no botão azul logo mais abaixo: **Responder à sua pergunta**.